# colab fit model error "not registered 'TFText>RoundRobinTrim'"

Tags: python, tensorflow

i trained BERT model at colab, used TPU for accelerator. the code like:

```
history = classifier.fit(train_preprocessed,
                     epochs=EPOCHS,
                     validation_data=val_preprocessed
                    )
```

then run this code line, shown error:

**NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'TFText>RoundRobinTrim' in binary running on n-8e0ea204-w-0. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.**

how could i solve this problem?

i will add additional info if needed.